# Executar comando no cmd com CD

Tags: cmd, composer

Estou querendo executar um comando específico do `composer update` pelo cmd. Porém, sempre preciso acessar a pasta da minha api com `cd` para executar a tal. Exemplo:

```
C:\Users\Luiz>cd api
C:\Users\Luiz\api>composer update
```

Existe uma maneira de fazer isso em um comando só? Tipo:

```
C:\Users\Luiz>cd api composer update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vc pode usar o `&` para executar comandos em uma só linha ex:

```
cd Links & dir
```

vc também pode usar o `&&` neste caso ele só executa o segundo comando se o primeiro for executado sem erros:

```
cd Links && dir
```

tente utilizando os seus comandos e seja feliz:

```
cd api & composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o path para a api já foi setada na variavél %path%, já tentou apenas executar **`call composer update`**? Veja essa resposta [Running “composer update” within a Windows .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309074/running-composer-update-within-a-windows-bat-file)

Use o comando **`cd`** == **`check directory`**, usando com a flag **`/d`**, faz ir até o drive, opção útil quando usando comandos entre pastas e drives diferentes.

O seu comando pode ser em uma linha usando operadores:

**• Observações sobre os operadores: &, |, && e ||**

```
execute & execute & execute

execute | recebe _saída_do_comando_anterior

execute | recebe _saída_do_comando_anterior & execute

executou_sem_erro && então_execute_também

executou_com_erro || execute_também_porque_deu_erro

executou_com_erro || executou_com_erro || executou_com_erro 

executou_sem_erro && executou_sem_erro && executou_sem_erro

executou_sem_erro && então_execute || execute_esse_no_primeiro_deu_erro
```

---

```
rem :: entre na pasta/check directory
cd /d "C:\Users\Luiz\api"
rem :: daí execute o update do compuser ::
composer update

rem :: ----------

rem :: para fazer em uma linha ::
cd /d "c:\Users\Luiz\api" && composer update 

rem :: usando variável %userprofile% do ambiente ::
rem :: usando operador && (execute (se executou sem erro) && também execute)
cd "%userprofile%\api" && composer update
```

---

Para a maioria das apis, o envio de comandos para execução se dá nessa sintaxe:

```
cmd /c cd /d "C:\Users\Luiz\api" && composer update
```

---

Já no compuser é diferente, nele você usa script por evento pré-definidos, ou algo do tipo.

Mas acredito que seria melhor dar uma olha na documentação que aborda as formas de adicionar [scripts/comandos no compuser](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-):

Uma [resposta tratando o uso de script no compuser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682416/run-command-line-command-in-composer-json)

Como [fazer um Calling Composer commands](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#calling-composer-commands)

Resposta [como rodar um cmd/bat para fazer o update do composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309074/running-composer-update-within-a-windows-bat-file)

5 macetes  [do compuser](https://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/php/composer-php-5-macetes/)

Answer (score 0):

```
set composerup=cd api ^& composer update
```

> execute o comadno:

```
%composerup%
```